# Automating jobs in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-cloud-services

I have questions regarding `automated jobs in Azure` but before I jump into my questions, I thought I'd explain our existing process.

As it stands, each of our clients have:

1. A windows service running on their server that polls a third-party cloud services every x seconds/minutes/hours. This windows service calls their SDK which passes the relevant username & password and calls the relevant API to check if data is available. If there is any, it will download the relevant document(s) and their associated metadata.

If multiple documents are available, it will download each document and their relevant data. Each document always has a metadata file associated with it.

2. Another windows service polls the specific location on their server where the documents and metadata from job (1) have been downloaded to. This in turns, processes the metadata & files and inserts them both into our database.

We need to be able to do the same in Azure but we need to do this for all our clients that will be running our cloud (multi-tenancy) solution.

1. Call a job to do the same as job (1) at specific interval. It should check if documents/metadata are available for each clients based on their specified interval (specific to each client). Some clients will process more data than others and/or some will require the information to be available more rapidly than others.

Not only will this job need to be called at specific interval as defined per client, it will also need to use the relevant username and password for each client to connect to our third-party cloud partner which has the metadata & documents stored on its system.

It will also need to handle failure:
  - Failed to connect to third-party
  - Failed to download a document and/or metadata.

2. Call a job to do the same as job (2) at specific interval. it should check if any documents/data have been downloaded by job (1) and process them i.e. insert the metadata and document in our database.

It will also need to handle failure:
  - Missing/Invalid metadata provided.
  - Missing Document.
  - Failed to insert data and/or document in database.

The way I see this work is as follows:

1. A job that connects to our third-part cloud partner at the specific interval will run in Azure. It will check if any document and metadata are available. If there are any, download both the document and metadata and add them to a queue.
2. A job will poll the queue and if anything is available in it, it will start processing the items from the queue.

While each client will have its own database, we'll have a master database that will contain all our clients database details i.e. connection string id, connection string, etc...

**Questions:**

1. Should we have one job (1) for each client or should we have just
           the one job (1) for all clients? if you think one job for all
           clients is the way to go, how will it handle independent intervals,
           username & password for third-party cloud partner for each client?
           Also how can this be scaled if required i.e. introduce a second or
           third job to do the same but each will process only a certain number
           of clients.
2. Should we have one job (2) for each client or should we have just
           the one job (2) for all clients? Again, same questions as in 1
               regarding interval, username & password to third-party cloud
               partner, scalability, etc... What about pricing/cost?
                Should we have one global queue or should have one queue for each client? If one queue per client, what does this
   entail regarding price/cost?
3. As each clients have their own databases, how will job (1) be aware
   of the relevant interval, username and password required to
               connected to third-party cloud partner? Should the job "loop"
               through our master database, get the relevant connection string,
               connect to the clients database and user their username & password and check their interval has been reached?
4. How will we know how to insert the relevant information in the
   relevant database when data is available in the queue. When job
       (1)is has downloaded the metadata and document and added it to the
               queue, should we also include the relevant connection string (or the id associated with this connection string) that will used again to
               obtain the username, password and interval so that it know which
               database to insert the data into? Is that acceptable or is there a better way to do this?
5. What's the difference between a `web job` and an Cloud Service worker
   role? Which one should we use?
6. Should we use a separate `cloud service` to run these `jobs` rather than
   running them on the same `cloud service` that will be hosting/running our web app?

Comment: Hey Thierry, you should consider asking this on the MSDN forums for WebJobs. This isn't a single question and some of it is opinion based which is against Stack Overflow etiquette. I'd have a hard time answering this here, as it is right now.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll do that. Reason I posted here is that it was recommended by MS as well as their forums, but totally understand what you're saying. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot answer all your questions (a lot of them depend on context), I can tell you how this kind of stuff on Azure at NubiloSoft. It's not for sale on the website, but we do use it within customer projects, handling high volumes of tasks every day.

First off, we've developed a scheduler framework. It's a single framework that works on multiple storage providers, but I'll just stick to Azure here. Basically the framework pushes jobs to Azure Queue storage (we use Table storage if they have too much metadata) for the reason that it's cheap. We then have a worker process running at several servers that pops off jobs and processes them.

A job (the thing we push on the storage) is basically a task ID with task meta. The ID is there to figure out what class should do the work, the meta contains the information necessary to run the task.

Now, special care is required for things like pop receipts. Basically you want to ensure that the pop receipt is prolongued if you haven't processed the job within the allotted time. If not (f.ex. because the server crashed) that allows the job to be rescheduled automatically. Note now that you need to pay extra care of error handling: if you throw an exception that crashes the worker thread, you must handle it properly or you just end up with jobs that keep on crashing. Also, we did a bit of work on proper logging, since troubleshooting for multiple jobs can be hard. When mixing table storage and queue storage you also need to take extra care with concurrency issues that might occur.

All in all, I can tell that it's quite a bit of work to get all this exactly right...

Still, with this in mind, I can answer your questions:

> Should we have one job (1) for each client or should we have just the one job (1) for all clients? if you think one job for all clients is the way to go, how will it handle independent intervals, username & password for third-party cloud partner for each client? Also how can this be scaled if required i.e. introduce a second or third job to do the same but each will process only a certain number of clients.

One worker role is best, because that allows you to do better scaling if the queue fills up. It's possible to configure auto-scaling for that.

As for username + pwd, for me it's just job meta-data. You can do whatever you want with it that matches the security constraints. I'd probably just try to store them along with the job meta in the queue, probably encrypted.

> Should we have one job (2) for each client or should we have just the one job (2) for all clients? Again, same questions as in 1 regarding interval, username & password to third-party cloud partner, scalability, etc...

I'd go for 1 queue and 1 role, purely from a scalability and performance perspective. If you have 1 queue and 10 workers, you basically poll the queue 10 times more often than with 1 role and 1 worker, thereby gaining more throughput. Also, using this approach you consolidate costs.

> What about pricing/cost? Should we have one global queue or should have one queue for each client? If one queue per client, what does this entail regarding price/cost?

One queue globally is cheaper, because it will give you less storage transactions. As for cost, it all depends on what you use. If you use cloud/queue storage, my experience is that it's irrelevant compared to the compute costs.

> As each clients have their own databases, how will job (1) be aware of the relevant interval, username and password required to connected to third-party cloud partner?

The scheduler takes care of the handling the intervals; the logic in the job tells the scheduler what the interval is. There's nothing more to it than that.

> What's the difference between a web job and an Cloud Service worker role? Which one should we use?

Web roles are for 'iis web applications', worker roles are for 'windows services'. Running a scheduler in IIS that will probably get recycled doesn't make much sense to me.

> Should we use a separate cloud service to run these jobs rather than running them on the same cloud service that will be hosting/running our web app?

I would.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll read it in more details later on and update accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for late response. While I understand what you're saying, I'm confused as to how one job will handle let's say 50 clients all needing their data to be downloaded from the remote site at the same time? I can expect client 50 to wait for the 49 previous to complete their download before I start downloading this, so will this be handled? Will the webjob need to perform the download using threading? What if that goes up to 500 clients or 5000 clients? How will that be handled?

Comment: @Thierry Very carefully :-) We run multiple threads per scheduler (in a custom thread pool). Each thread handles tasks. In our case, if we have way more tasks than we can chew on, we spawn a new worker role (based on the queue size). Note that you can make tasks as big or small as you want - you can f.ex. process part of the download per queue item -- whatever seems reasonable within time allowed for the task to complete. Also, realize that queues are good for tasks that can wait; if you're doing a real-time system, it might be better to simply spawn threads and workers.

Comment: Either way, if you have more clients than you have bandwidth (both processing and network), you have to wait or spawn workers. There's no magic trick for that. In cases where we need to handle lots of network bandwidth we usually use async IO and async (reactor/proactor) processing. Queue's are a solution for reliability - nothing more, nothing less - the rest is just programming.

Comment: Ok, good to know. We don't need real-time but my concern is that we want to allow clients to specify how often they want their invoices (tif/pdf) and metadata pulled from this third-party cloud solution and if none change their default, I want to make sure that all clients can request theirs at the same time rather than having to wait for one client to finish. So to handle this scenario, threads will be required and I guess a way to monitor how many thread are currently being used by the webjob. If the max is being used, spawn another webjob, correct?

Comment: @Thierry As I said, we use worker roles - but yes, you need threads for processing and probably async io if you need high performance network traffic (network async io doesn't usually work with threads, but in a more efficient way). You need different counters for both probably, or some auto-tuning async io to optimize throughput dynamically (that's what we do). In Azure, Auto scaling can be set on queue size, so that's the easy part.